# Как я могу передать элемент из итерируемого списка из функции sort () в аргумет key в str.replace method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Beverage:
    def __init__(self, ingredients: list):
        self.ingredients = ingredients

    def get_cost(self):
        ingredients = self.ingredients
        sort = list(filter(lambda tup : tup[0] in ingredients, prices.items()))
        self.cost = sum([tup[1] for tup in sort])
        return f'${self.cost:.2f}'

    def get_price(self):
        return f'${self.cost * 2.5:.2f}'

    def get_name(self):
        ingredients = self.ingredients
        ingredients.sort()
        ingredients.append('Smoothie') if len(ingredients) == 1 else ingredients.append('Fusion')

        # How can i change this code?:

        ingredients = list(map(lambda ingredient: ingredient.replace('berries', 'berry'), ingredients))

        # i want this:

        # ingredients = sorted(ingredients, key=str.replace(ingredients.getitem(?...?), 'berries', 'berry'))

        # it's possible?

        return ' '.join(ingredients)

b = Beverage(['Banana', 'Mango', 'Raspberries'])
print(b.get_cost())
print(b.get_price())
print(b.get_name())
```

Comment: Попробуйте `key=lambda x: x.replace('berries', 'berry'))`.

Comment: Спасибо за этот ответ, но хотелось бы понять, можно ли вызвать итерируемый элемент и если да, то как? В отличие от циклов, в sorded(), min(), max() не присваивается переменная, чтобы можно было обратиться к item. Но ведь как-то доступ к нему возможен... или нет?

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса. Что значит `вызвать итерируемый элемент`?

Comment: Проходя по циклу for, я могу обратиться к каждому элементу последовательности. Я указываю для этого переменную, например item. Но функции sorted, max, min также проходят по последовательности. Я бы хотел как-то получить доступ к очередному элементу, обратиться к нему напрямую. Например как в коде выше: не из строки вызвать метод replace(), а из классa - str.replace(). И вот во втором случае метод replace принимает не 2 аргумента, а 3. Каждый элемент последовательности, который я поместил в функцию sorted - это строка. Я хочу обратиться к очередному элементу и поместить в str.replace. Возможно?

Comment: Данную задачку лучше решать не через список, а через словарь. На днях на курсах тоже столкнулся с данной задачкой, то есть где "поиграться" :D

Comment: `key=lambda x: str.replace(x, 'berries', 'berry')`  в принципе ничем не отличается от первого комментария.